# My Shut Down menu is partially in English

Tags: macbook-pro, shutdown, internationalization

After macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 Supplemental Update 2, my Shut Down menu changed from Dutch to English, but only partially:

[image: The macOS Shut Down menu, with some text that is partially in Dutch]

I tried adding and removing Dutch and English in the Language & Region System Preferences pane, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked for me is following the instructions to [change the language used at the login screen on your Mac](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202036), namely:

1. Switch to admin account
2. Open Terminal.app
3. Run `sudo languagesetup`
4. Enter 9 (which indicates Dutch, my preferred language)
5. Reboot